# iOS - Combine - Change Publisher type to child type

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have these two Codable objects :

```
struct Parent: Codable {
    let name: String
    let children: [Child]
}

struct Child: Codable {
    let name: String
}
```

That I have created to match this json :

```
{
    name: "test"
    children: (
        {
          name: "test2"
        },
        {
          name: "test3"
        }
     )
}
```

I retrieve the json and decode it to a Parent object using these methods :

```
func parent(_ url: String) -> AnyPublisher<Parent, Error> { 
    return dataFromURL(url)
        .map(\.value)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

struct Result<T> {
    let value: T
    let response: URLResponse
}

func dataFromURL<T: Decodable>(_ url: String, _ decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) -> AnyPublisher<Result<T>, Error> {
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:url)!)
    return URLSession.shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .tryMap { result -> Result<T> in
            let value = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: result.data)
            return Result(value: value, response: result.response)
        }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

It works, but I would like a method to retrieve the array of children, instead of the Parent object, like this :

```
func children(_ url: String) -> AnyPublisher<[Child], Error>
```

But I don't know what I need to change.. Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to call your `parent` function and call `map` on its `Publisher` to get back its `children` property.

```
func children(from url: String) -> AnyPublisher<[Child], Error> {
    return parent(url)
        .map(\.children)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Unrelated to your question, but I'd suggest getting rid of your `Result` type. First of all, it conflicts with Swift's built-in `Result` type. Secondly, storing the `URLResponse` in case of a successful network requests, which returned valid data doesn't really add any value. The `URLResponse` mainly holds value in case of failure or if the request doesn't return a value, but a success response code (200, 206, etc).

Update: if you want to get rid of your `parent(_:)` method, you simply need to chain the `map(\.children)` call to the contents of your original `parent(_:)` method. In order to let the compiler infer the generic return type of the `dataFromURL(_:)` method, you simply need to specify the `KeyPath` as `\Parent.children` in your second `map` call.

```
func children(from url: String) -> AnyPublisher<[Child], Error> {
    return dataFromURL(url)
        .map(\.value)
        .map(\Parent.children)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Would it be possible to keep the children method and making it work without the parent method ?

Comment: @Xys actually found a much simpler implementation, updated my answer again